# NSString to NSDate with setDateFormat

Tags: parsing, nsstring, nsdate

I have a problem with `NSDateFormatter` parsing a string coming from the web.

I parse dates as string and transform them to `NSDate`. The problem is in choosing the correct format string.

Parsed dates have following "format":

```
Feb 04, 2014 8:00 AM ET
```

but I haven't find the correct format to transform them into an `NSDate`

I've tried with: `EEE dd, yyyy hh:mm a` but it is not working.

Code is simple:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *articleDate = [formatter dateFromString:articleDateString];
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to convert your `NSString` to `NSDate`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a 'ET'"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];
NSDate *articleDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Feb 04, 2014 8:00 AM ET"];
NSLog(@"-->%@",articleDate);
```

Comment: Well.. can i use this method in other date format? i've tried to use for: Sun, 2 Feb 2014 23:30:00 EDT ... --> EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'EDT'..???

Comment: Yes.. but you need to change date format whenever your string changes

Answer (score 0):

Using this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Change your "EEE" to "MMM" and add a "z" at the end to catch your timezone.

"EEE" is day of week, for example, "Tue", not month.

Comment: Thank you.. but not working again.

i've used:

    "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a z"
     "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a zzz"
    
     "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a z"
     "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a zzz"